# Identifying $\langle x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\mid x_1x_2=x_3, x_3x_2=x_1, x_1x_4=x_3, x_3x_4=x_1\rangle$.

Tags: group-theory, gap, group-presentation

What group is $\langle x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\mid x_1x_2=x_3, x_3x_2=x_1, x_1x_4=x_3, x_3x_4=x_1\rangle$?

*Thoughts:*

The group is infinite according to GAP, $x_2=x_4$, and $x_2^2=id.$

Comment: Is there any context where this comes up?

Comment: Yes, @AlexProvost: use Cayley's theorem to convert $C_2\times C_2$ into a group of permutations, namely $\{id., (13), (24), (13)(24)\}$, then permute the generators according to these permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $x_3:=x_1x_2$ the relations become $x_1x_2^2=x_1$, so $x_2^2=1$, and
$x_4=x_1^{-1}x_1x_2=x_2$. The last relation $x_3x_4=x_1$ then just says $x_1=x_1$. So, writing $x_1=a,x_2=b$ the group is given by
$$
\langle a,b \mid b^2=1\rangle,
$$
and now you see it.

Comment: So, it's the free product of $\Bbb Z$ with $C_2$?

Comment: Right - in contrast to [this group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49315/what-group-is-langle-a-b-a2-b2-rangle).